# implications of convex function with an increasing relative change of first derivative

Tags: calculus, convex-analysis

Consider a thrice differentiable function f on the nonnegative reals with $f(0)=0$, $ f'(x) \gt 0 $ and $ f''(x) \gt 0 $ for all $ x \gt 0 $. Also, $ \lim_{x\to 0} f'(x)=0 $ and  $\frac{f''(x)}{f'(x)}$ is strictly increasing. I want to know if for all closed intervals [a,b], where $ a\gt 0$  $$h(x)= \frac{f'(x)}{f''(x)}\frac{f'''(x)}{f''(x)}\lt 2$$
So far, I have not found a counterexample such the latter expression is greater than two. For example, $\frac{f''(x)}{f'(x)}$ is not strictly increasing if $f(x)= \frac{x^{1+\alpha}}{1+\alpha}$, where $\alpha \gt 0$, because $\frac{f''(x)}{f'(x)}=\frac{\alpha}{x}$. I have tried a function with exponential terms: $f(x)=e^{e^x}-(1+x)e$. In this case,   $h(x)=1+\frac{e^x}{(1+e^x)^2}-\frac{e}{e^{e^x}(1+e^x)^2}-\frac{e}{e^{e^x}e^x}$, which reaches a global maximum lower than 2 aproximately at x=1,32. Note that it tends to 1 as x goes to infinity and to zero when x goes to zero.

On the other hand, as $h(x)$ is continuous, I considered its first derivative to evaluate whether the maximum value of $h(x)$ in a given closed interval is less than two. In order to to this, the first order condition if there is an interior solution is $$\frac{dh(x)}{dx}=\frac{(f''f'''+f'f'''')f''f''-2f'f''f'''f'''}{(f''f'')^2}=0$$.

After rearranging, I get $h(x)=\frac{1}{2-g(x)}$, where $g(x)=\frac{f''f''''}{f'''f'''}$.
As $\frac{f''(x)}{f'(x)}$ is strictly increasing, after setting its first derivative to be greater than zero and rearranging, $ h(x)\gt 1$  or, equivalently, $\frac{f'''}{f''} \gt \frac{f''}{f'}$. Thus, after using a similar argument $ g(x)\gt 1$. But then $ 1 \lt g(x)\lt 2$. If $g(x)\gt 1,5$ then $ h(x)\gt 2$. I cannot see a reason why that is not possible. I did not try interior solutions as for the last result.

We can go further if we assume that $\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}$ is strictly increasing. Then define $l(x)= \frac{f(x)}{f'(x)}\frac{f''(x)}{f'(x)}$. After using the previous reasoning and results, $ 1 \lt h(x)\lt 2$ if there is an interior solution for a given closed interval [a,b] whenever maximizing $l(x)$. If the maximum occurs at a, then $l(x)\lt \frac{1}{2-h(x)}$; clearly, $ 1 \lt h(x)\lt 2$ as $l(x)\gt 0$. If instead the maximum occurs at b, I can not rule out that $h(x)\gt 2$.